# O que há de errado no meu código QuickSort em C?

Tags: c, números-aleatórios, quicksort

Aqui está o meu código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int lista[1000];
int tamanho;
main () {
  printf("Tamanho: ");
  scanf("%d", & tamanho);
  int c;
  for (c = 0; c < tamanho; c++) {
    lista[c] = c + 1;
  }
  misturar();
  for (c = 0; c < tamanho; c++) {
    printf("%d ", lista[c]);
  }
  quick(lista, 0, tamanho - 1);
}
misturar() {
  int a,b,backup;
  for (a = 0; a < tamanho; a++) {
    b = rand() % tamanho;
    backup = lista[a];
    lista[a] = lista[b];
    lista[b] = backup;
  }
}
quick(int *tabela, int ini, int fim) {
  int a,b,pivo,backup;
  a = ini;
  b = fim;
  pivo = tabela[(a + b) / 2];
  while (a < b) {
    while (tabela[a] < pivo) {
      a = a + 1;
    }
    while (tabela[b] > pivo) {
      b = b + 1;
    }
    if (a <= b) {
      backup = tabela[a];
      tabela[a] = tabela[b];
      tabela[b] = backup;
      a = a + 1;
      b = b - 1;
    }
  }
  if (b > ini) {
    quick(*tabela, ini, b - 1);
  }
  if (a < fim) {
    quick(*tabela, a, fim - 1);
  }
}
```

O meu compilador é Code Blocks,
Esse é o resultado
[image: Esse é o resultado]

Comment: Para não gerares sempre os mesmos números aleatórios, faz `srand(time(NULL));` logo no inicio da tua função `main()`. Lembra de fazer `#include <time.h>`.

Answer (score 1):

Assim à primeira vista detectei dois erros (não compilei ou corri o teu código):

o `b` tem que andar para trás

```
    while (tabela[b] > pivo) {
      // b = b + 1; // OOPS
      b = b - 1;
    }
```

e para chamares a função `quick()` recursivamente tens de usar o paramatro correcto

```
  if (b > ini) {
    // quick(*tabela, ini, b - 1);
    quick(tabela, ini, b - 1);
  }
  if (a < fim) {
    // quick(*tabela, a, fim - 1);
    quick(tabela, a, fim - 1);
  }
```

Sugestão: liga o máximo de warnings do teu compilador e presta-lhes atenção. O compilador tem de te avisar na chamada recursiva (o erro da indexação com `b` não é apanhado pelos warnings).

Comment: Obrigado pelo erros que você notou, mas o meu quicksort ainda não está funcionando, como faço para ligar o alerta de warning no máximo?

Answer (score -1):

Você está fazendo as coisas na ordem errada, a certa seria: misturar >> ordenar >> printar;

Ou você poderia fazer assim: misturar >> printar >> ordenar >> printar;